# How to assign imported module to dictionary type with index signature in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, module, compiler-errors

*my_dates.ts*

```
export const birthday = new Date(1992, 12, 14);
export const anniversary = new Date(2014, 5, 9);
export const moonLanding = new Date(1969, 6, 20);
```

*index.ts*

```
import * as myDates from './my_dates';
type MyDateType = {[k: string]: Date};
let foo: MyDateType = myDates as MyDateType;
```

I get the following error:

```
Type 'typeof "<project>/my_dates"' cannot be converted to type 'MyDateType'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'typeof "<project>/my_dates"'.
```

What's the reason it doesn't let me assign it?

- I've tried with and without the type casting.
- If I use `type MyDateType = {[k: string]: any};` instead, it works, but then I lose all the type information in `foo`.
- Intellisense in VSCode is able to autocomplete the myDates variable without any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I haven't seen people try to change the type of the namespace like that before.  Well, [rest/spread object destructuring](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) seems to work:

```
import * as myDates from './my_dates';
type MyDateType = { [k: string]: Date };
let foo = { ...myDates } as MyDateType; // works
const a: Date = foo.anniversary; // okay
const b: Date = foo.birthday; // okay
const m: Date = foo.mothersDay; // STILL okay, but you asked for it
```

I'm not sure why you want to throw away the knowledge of the exact keys present in `myDates`, but that's up to you.  Note: if you add some non-`Date` property to `my_dates.ts`, the `MyDateType` assertion will fail as expected.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Ahhh, I was under the impression that it would be smart enough to keep the knowledge of the existing keys when I assigned it to `foo`. I'll try to work around that and use a more strict type as `MyDateType`. I still need a lot of getting used to how all this typing works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The interface of the import matches `{[k: string]: any}` which can't be directly changed to `{[k: string]: Date}` via a type assertion, which is why you get the error.

If you know for sure that there will only ever be exports of type Date within the module then you can use:

```
let foo: MyDateType = myDates as any as MyDateType;
```

but a better solution may be to structure the my_dates module so it looks like:

```
export const birthday = new Date(1992, 12, 14);
export const anniversary = new Date(2014, 5, 9);
export const moonLanding = new Date(1969, 6, 20);

const myDates = { birthday, anniversary, moonLanding };

export default myDates;
```

or something similar depending on your needs.

Then to import this:

```
import myDates from './foo';
```

and this will already have a type which can be type asserted.